# Как прикрутить Qiwi к самописному сайту?

Tags: веб-программирование, qiwi

Нашел статью: [Подключаем Qiwi кошелек к интернет-магазину](http://berezablog.com/podklyuchaem-qiwi-koshelek-k-internet-magazinu/), вроде там очень просто - регистрируешься, утверждают, встраиваешь код на сайт.

Кто-нибудь таким занимался?
Задача стоит - сделать продажу билетов. Т.е. цена товара фиксированная, может только количество меняться.

Answer (score 1):

Прикрутите лучше сразу агрегатор платежей, например http://robokassa.ru/, подробная инструкция на их сайте имеется.